# How to manage the enable/disable of GUI components in one app

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I'm doing an app with lots of buttons and menus and I want enable and disable the buttons and menu items when the actions attached to them can or can not be performed. ie the save button and the save menu item only will be active when there are unsaved changes.

Question: How can I do this efficiently/Which is the correct way to do this?

One solution can be have a private variable for each button and menu entry and enable/disable it as needed.
Other solution can be get all the components of the JToolBar and the JMenu in an array and iterate over all them and enable/disable as needed.
But I think there are better solutions. Any help or guideline will be apreciated.

edit: The question is not how to enable/disable a single button or menu item, I will know how can I manage the state of all the buttons and menu items of the app. Which is the best way to achive this?. I have explained some solutions in which I have been thinkin, but none of them convince me.

Comment: "Which is the best way to achive this?" - this is not constructive. Best in what sense? What you are trying to optimize?

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov May be the question should be "How can I achieve this?"
I just want to know the the way in which this is normally do in the apps.

Comment: I think here is user experience is more important than technical solution. Imagine you have a button, user click but nothing happens, it would confuse him. In that case it is better to disable it from clicking.

Comment: Yea! that's what I want to do. But the question is how manage the large number of buttons and menu items to enable/disable them as needed. Having a private variable of each button/menu item to can refer to them is the way to go?

Comment: It depends on on/off patterns. Use some collection to keep buttons.

Answer (score 4):

The `Action` class already supports this. See the [`Action#isEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#isEnabled%28%29) and [`Action#setEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) methods. Calling the setter will fire an event, on which the UI on which this `Action` is set will enable/disable itself.

The `Action` can be seen as the model for your UI buttons/menu items/... . All state is stored and updated in the model, and the view needs to reflect this (MVC pattern).

Comment: technically, the model for a button is [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html) but yes, it's a way to manage the state

Answer (score 1):

1) to disable from clicking use:

`JButton#setEnabled(boolean)`

and

`JMenuItem#setEnabled(boolean)`

2) to disable `ActionListener` for some time use a private boolean variable inside

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
    if (!enabled) return;

    // rest of code
}
```